# Why did Galadriel suspect this character?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power

In *The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power*, S01E08, we see that Galadriel suddenly got suspicious of Halbrand. we clearly see this on the plot which Halbrand started offering Celebrimbor advice on how to make artifacts of power, and called it a *“gift”*.

The reason of suspicion is ambiguous for me. Galadriel seemed to care about this character as she thought he was the promised king of the southerns and even brought him to receive elvish treatment after he was wounded in war.

Why did she get suspicious? Was him giving advice to *Celebrimor* a reason?

Comment: Because Celebrimbor started making comments previously heard by Galadriel from Adar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Galadriel is interrogating Adar in episode 6, he tells her:

> After Morgoth's defeat, the one you call Sauron, he sought to craft a **power not of the flesh, but over flesh**.

Later, when in conference with Gil-Galad, she hears Celebrimbor say these same words when describing how the mithril crown could prevent the decay and allow the elves to remain in Middle-Earth. After Gil-Galad approves the work and leaves, Galadriel presses Celebrimbor on where he heard those words and he reveals that it was from Halbrand.

She becomes suspicious because of these words and realises the crown would have the power that Sauron sought.